# How to turn off the webcam after using Pubnub?

Tags: webcam, pubnub

I started to use Pubnub for making video group chats. However, when I was testing it, I found a little problem: As I connect my computer to their servers, my webcam turns on and never turns off, unless I leave the page.

However, I wish to be able to close a video chatting, and turning off the webcam at the same time. How to do it?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Here is a code I'm using for my tests, I'm using the one given in the tutorial:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pubnub-3.7.18.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/webrtc.js"></script>
<script src="js/rtc-controller.js"></script>
<div id="vid-box"></div>
<div id="vid-thumb"></div>

<form name="loginForm" id="login" action="#" onsubmit="return login(this);">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Pick a username!" />
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Log In">
</form>


<form name="callForm" id="call" action="#" onsubmit="return makeCall(this);">
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter user to dial!" />
    <input type="submit" value="Call"/>
</form>

<div id="inCall"> <!-- Buttons for in call features -->
    <button id="end" onclick="end()">End</button> <button id="mute" onclick="mute()">Mute</button> <button id="pause" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
</div>
<script>
    var video_out = document.getElementById("vid-box");
    var vid_thumb = document.getElementById("vid-thumb");
    function login(form) {
        var phone = window.phone = PHONE({
            number        : form.username.value || "Anonymous", // listen on username line else Anonymous
            media : { audio : true, video : true },
            publish_key   : 'pub-c-c66a9681-5497-424d-b613-e44bbbea45a0',
            subscribe_key : 'sub-c-35aca7e0-a55e-11e5-802b-02ee2ddab7fe',
        }); 
        var ctrl = window.ctrl = CONTROLLER(phone);
        ctrl.ready(function(){
            form.username.style.background="#55ff5b"; // Turn input green
            form.login_submit.hidden="true";    // Hide login button
            ctrl.addLocalStream(vid_thumb);     // Place local stream in div
        });             // Called when ready to receive call
        ctrl.receive(function(session){
            session.connected(function(session){ video_out.appendChild(session.video); });
            session.ended(function(session) { ctrl.getVideoElement(session.number).remove(); });
        });
        ctrl.videoToggled(function(session, isEnabled){
            ctrl.getVideoElement(session.number).toggle(isEnabled); // Hide video is stream paused
        });
        ctrl.audioToggled(function(session, isEnabled){
            ctrl.getVideoElement(session.number).css("opacity",isEnabled ? 1 : 0.75); // 0.75 opacity is audio muted
        });
        return false; //prevents form from submitting
    }

    function makeCall(form){
        if (!window.ctrl) alert("Login First!");
        else ctrl.dial(form.number.value);
        return false;
    }
    function end(){
        ctrl.hangup();
    }
    function mute(){
        var audio = ctrl.toggleAudio();
        if (!audio) $("#mute").html("Unmute");
        else $("#mute").html("Mute");
    }

    function pause(){
        var video = ctrl.toggleVideo();
        if (!video) $('#pause').html('Unpause');
        else $('#pause').html('Pause');
    }
</script>
```

Note that I tried to find the function through the console in addition to my searches, but I was unable to find it...

Comment: hi! would you be able to paste some of your code for reproduction?

Comment: I edited my post with a code I'm using for my tests. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try the **`phone.stop()`** command?

Comment: Yes, and I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: phone.stop is not a function
I also tried with ctrl.stop(), just in case...

Comment: You need to get the latest SDK from the GitHub Repository.